# PHP Form variable and data to & from text file?

Tags: php, forms, file, variables

I have a form with quite a lot of input fields and checkboxes.

When I submit the form I want to write the form field name and value to a text file.

```
<input type="text" name="mailHost" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="mailUser" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="mailPass" value=""/>
```

So with this as an example it would be written to a file as :

```
mailHost = VALUE
mailUser = VALUE
mailPass = VALUE
```

For a few form fields it fine doing each on by hand, but is there a function or way to do this for numerous fields ?

And then the same for reading it back ?

Again using the same example above I'd end up with the following when read back :

$mailHost = Value, $mailUser = value etc where the variable name is dynamically created and the value assigned ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through your `$_POST` array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   file_put_contents('file.txt', $key . " = " . $value . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

**NOTE**

Unchecked checkboxes will not in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Thanks - how about reading it back so I get the variable name as the $key ?

Comment: Check the `file()`, `expolde()` function in PHP manual, and read some about `Arrays`